# Can't find "terminal" in Unity (16.04)

Tags: unity, 16.04, gnome-terminal, desktop-environments

My server is Ubuntu 16.04 hosted by linode. I followed the linode doc to install Unity/Gnome, but I can't find "terminal" in "applications->accessories", nor can I find it in any other applications. How do I enable it?

[image]

Comment: Do you see it in "System Tools"? Otherwise, try Ctrl + Alt + T.

Comment: OK. I find "xterm" and "uxterm", never occured to me they could be terminal. Thanks.   But why "terminal" is replaced by them?

Comment: Along with Ctrl + alt + t, you can try Ctrl + Alt + F1 to get TTY1 and from there do sudo apt-get install xterm and you should see it under one of the categories.

Comment: @shenkwen Not sure why terminal is missing for you. You can install it by running `sudo apt install gnome-terminal` in a TTY or xterm or uxterm.

Comment: OK, first of all, what I see on thay screenshot is not Unity desktop, but rather old Gnome desktop. So you seem to be using old Ubuntu version. Terminal should be under system tools or utilities. otherwise you can always go into tty via right ctrl + F1.